# Load database value with function

Tags: php

I didn't see any topic like this so I posted a new one.
First of all, I'm sorry about my bad English.

I want an public function who can storage in a global variable a value from database, and with that value the php script select the website templates. Can you help me?

```
    private $page_title = null;
private $body_title = null;
private $body_content = null;
private $template = null;
private $settings = array();
private $file_template = 'content';
private $path = 'templates/';
private $parse_page = false;
global $template2;

public function GetHASH()
{
    return $this->hash;
}

function Tema()
{
    global $db,$user_class;
    if($user_class->authorized)
    {
        $row = $db->sql("SELECT * FROM `ucp_users` WHERE `user_hash` = '".$this->GetHASH()."'");
        $array = $db->get_array($row);
        $template2 = $array['template'];
    }
    else
    {
        $template2 = '1';
    }
    return $template2;
}
function __construct() { 
    switch($template2) {
        default:
        {
            $template_name = 'dsa/';
            $template2 = 1;
        }
        break;
        case 0: $template_name = 'lsrp/';
        break;
        case 1: $template_name = 'dsa/';
        break;
    }
    $this->path = $this->path.''.$template_name;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: So what exactly is going wrong with what you already have?

Comment: Is this within a class?

Comment: Yes is in a class and the function "Tema" don't load the variable from database. $template2 is 0 for all what i can do

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate your class, the constructor is called, at this time your tema method has not been invoked yet since it cannot be called without an instance. One solution would be to call your tema method in your constructor like this :

```
function __construct() {
  $template2 = this->tema(); 
  switch($template2) {
    default:
    {
        $template_name = 'dsa/';
        $template2 = 1;
    }
    break;
    case 0: $template_name = 'lsrp/';
    break;
    case 1: $template_name = 'dsa/';
    break;
  }
  $this->path = $this->path.''.$template_name;
```

}